# Exponentiation of a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation

By the definition of matrix exponentiation,

$$A^k = \begin{cases}
I_n, & \text{if } k=0  \\[1ex]
A^{k-1}A, & \text{if } k\in \mathbb {N}_0  \\
\end{cases}$$

In my book, there's an exercise to do $D^k$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix.
In the solutions, though, they wrote

$$D^k=\operatorname{diag}(d_1^k, \dots , d_n^k)$$

Which one is correct?

Comment: yeah, I edited it sry

Comment: Both are correct. Because if you multiply two diagonal matrices $D_1 = diag(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ and $D_2 = diag(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$, then $D_1D_2 = diag(d_1e_1,\ldots,d_ne_n)$. So, $D_1^2 = diag(d_1^2,\ldots,d_n^2)$.

Comment: Where do you see a possible mistake, i dont see stuff that contradict each other

Comment: This is like asking which one is correct, the Fibonacci recurrence or the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct but they are two different topics.

$$A^k=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
I_n, if\, k=0  \\
A^{k-1}A, if\, k\in {\displaystyle \mathbb {N} }_0  \\
\end{array}
\right.$$
is the definition of the matrix power $A^k$ in general.

On the other hand $$D^k=diag(d_1\,^k, ... , d_n\,^k)$$ is a special case where your matrix is a diagonal matrix.

There is no conflict because the second one is just the application of the first one to the diagonal matrix $$D=diag(d_1,d_2, ... , d_n)$$

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Let $$D=\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c \end{bmatrix}.$$ then by the property of diagonal matrix
$$f(D)=\begin{bmatrix} f(a) & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & f(b) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & f(c) \end{bmatrix}$$ So  $$D^k= \begin{bmatrix} a^k & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & b^k & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c^k \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$D^0 =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: That makes sense, however if it wasn't diagonal (which I said it was) this wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: I don't think this is an answer. What is the domain of $f$? It is true that we can "overload" notation in cases like $f(x) = x^k$ since the notion of $X^k$ for matrices $X$ works. But in other cases like $f(x) = e^x$, what does $f(X)$ for a matrix $X$ mean? We have to define what $e^X$ means (usually done using Taylor series), and in the case of diagonal matrix it just so happens that it does amount to exponentiating each diagonal entry. Never mind what happens for more bizarre functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.